# Debian: "command -v <command>" still returns path after removing the package?

Tags: bash, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, apt

I've uninstalled the stylus package on my Debian by `sudo apt-get remove --purge node-stylus`.

Now it says when I try to run the `stylus` command: `stylus: command not found`. So it works as it should.

But in my scripts I check whether Stylus is installed or not by:

```
if ! command -v sudo stylus &> /dev/null; then
    echo "ERROR: Stylus is not installed!"
    exit 1
fi
```

And for some reason `command -v stylus` still returns `/usr/bin/stylus` thus the script won't fail.

I checked `/usr/bin/` and there is no stylus there.

Could someone explain to me please why does this work like this?

Comment: Note: your syntax is invalid. `command -v <command_name>`. It takes no arguments. But so. You are testing `sudo`, not `stylus` command.

Comment: Oh, so if the user is root, I can put anything after sudo, it will return true because sudo is there?
Hmm, but in the case of "apache2" I can only test it with sudo, without that apache2 is non-existent.

Comment: If Apache is installed, you just need to include its directory on the `PATH` for `command` to find it. You definitely don't need `sudo` for that.

Comment: And what's the explanation for working with sudo and not working without it? It's in the PATH for root but not for everyone else? Sorry, I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash maintains a cache for lookups; you want to do

```
hash -r stylus
```

to force it to forget the old value.

Separately, of course, don't use `command -v sudo` when you actually want `command -v stylus`, as already pointed out in a comment.

Comment: I tried running the command but it returns: hash: stylus: not found. Now the command command returns nothing but that's maybe due to the fact that I rebooted Debian since then. Maybe that's why hash can't find it as well. But the if case mentioned in the post still doesn't evaulate to true.

Comment: The reboot would have already fixed the problem by itself. Running `hash` forces Bash to forget the cached value it has in memory, and the error message is actually an indication that it did what you asked, i.e. forgot the hashed value. (You can obviously discard the error message with `hash -r stylus 2>/dev/null` if you like.)

Comment: You still have the `sudo` problem in your code which was already pointed out in a comment. I assumed you already figured out that your code should not use that.